# Rubymine torquebox java_opts

Tags: rubymine, torquebox

I'm trying to use rubymine with torquebox server.

Everything is almost successful, but I cannot find where to set java_opts.
When I start debugging, application fails with OutOfMemory error.

So I think I have to increase Xmx and Xms values, but don't know where with this settings.

- Rubymine 5.4.2
- rvm with jruby 1.7.4
- gem torquebox-server 2.3.0
- gem torquebox 2.3.0
- gem ruby-debug-base (0.10.5.rc9-java)
- gem ruby-debug-ide (0.4.23.beta1)

Thanks for help, google doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It seems it should be set in:

Configuration select box> Edit configurations> Select Development > tab Configuration> Environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You can set in:

Goes to Configuration select box> "Edit Configurations"> Select Development > Tab "Configuration"

On the field "Server arguments" put the Xmx param, for example: --jvm-options="-Xmx1024m"